# How to scale entire document or use bigger fonts?

Tags: fontsize, paper-size, size, scale

I want to create a latex document for solving exercises online.
Beamer is one option, but I would need a full A4 page for writing down the solution with my tablet using a PDF annotator.
Since writing a latex article class is simpler than writing beamer, I'd prefer article, but would need 200% bigger font. Changing the format to A5 paper somewhat does the trick, but I'd prefer A4 with font e.g. 24 or bigger (easier printing and PDF annotating).

Comment: With the `extsizes` package, you can use the `[20pt]` option with the `extarticle` or `extreport` classes.

Comment: Try the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report` classes and can output `article` style documents) which provides font sizes from 9pt to 60pt for the general text.

Answer (score 1):

Your options include:

- Load `fontspec` with a `Scale=` parameter as `\defaultfontfeatures`.
- Load `\usepackage[fontsize=24]{scrextend}` to get Koma-Script’s features.
- Load `extsize` and load `\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}`, the largest size the manual says it supports.
- Load a font package with its `[scaled=...]` option, if it has one.

Comment: this isnt enough to do anything with. lazy answer :/

Comment: @jheriko The question can be solved with several one-line commands.